# Can a change of variables in a dynamical system result in a solution that can not be mapped back to the original solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Can a change of variables in a dynamical system result in a solution that can not be mapped back to the original solution?  Specifically, consider the dynamical system

\begin{align}
x^\prime(t) &= f(x(t)), &x(0) &= x_0
\end{align}

where $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^m$.  Given an invertible map $\phi : \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ where $y(t)=\phi(x(t))$, we can define a new system

\begin{align}
y^\prime(t) &= \phi^\prime(x(t))x^\prime(t) \\
&= \phi^\prime(x(t))f(x(t)) \\
&= \phi^\prime(\phi^{-1}(y(t)))f(\phi^{-1}(y(t))
\end{align}

or that

\begin{align}
y^\prime(t) &= \phi^\prime(\phi^{-1}(y(t)))f(\phi^{-1}(y(t))), &y(0) &= \phi(x_0)
\end{align}

Does the system for $x$ have a solution if and only if $y$ has a solution?  If so, can we always map one solution to the other using $\phi$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the fact that $\phi$ is invertible and apply the rule of differentiation of the inverse function.

For simplicity I only consider the case $\phi:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\,$:

Let $x$ be a solution of $\dot x=f(x)\,.$ Then $y=\phi(x)$ is a solution of
$$
\dot y=\phi'(x)\,\dot x=\phi'(\phi^{-1}(y))\,f(\phi^{-1}(y))\,.
$$
Conversely, let $y$ be a solution of that last system which we write more briefly as
$$
\dot y=g(y)
$$
where $g(y)=((\phi'f)\circ\psi)(y)$ and $\psi:=\phi^{-1}\,.$ Then $x=\psi(y)$ is a solution of
$$
\dot x=\psi'(y)\,\dot y=\psi'(\phi(x))\,g(\phi(x))=\frac{1}{\phi'(\psi(\phi(x)))}((\phi'f)\circ\psi)(\phi(x))=\frac{\phi'(x)f(x)}{\phi'(x)}=f(x)\,.
$$